# convert jpg images into a video

Tags: video, jpeg

I have a bunch of jpg images i want to turn into a video, i have tried 
[JPGVideo](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/jpgvideo.html) but it did not work.
any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

You need a **"stopmotion"** maker: here's an [overview](http://www.stopmotionworks.com/stopmosoftwr.htm) of them, and one to download: [CellSoft Take5 1.30](http://take5.cellsoft.qarchive.org/)

If you're linux, there's a "stopmotion" package ready for one-click-install.

Comment: "stopmotion" software is a wee bit overkill for what idober wants to do, isn't it?

Comment: well, these question are being asked here because folks want to hear how it is done and which software is suitable (preferably from users who have some experience with the program they recommend), they don't want to be sent off to google. :)

Comment: You're right :) I just thought idober wasn't aware of the "stop-motion" term used to name this kind of stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use [ImagesToVideo](http://en.cze.cz/Images-to-video) (free):

[image]

Also there is [Time-Lapse Tool](http://www.timelapsetool.com/) ($50):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. download and run [**Portable Movie Maker**](http://devrexster.googlepages.com/mmk)
2. import images
3. drag and drop images to the story board
4. save movie ... done and dusted.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1:

```
cat ~/scripts/compile_movie.sh 
#!/bin/sh
mencoder "mf://*.jpg" -fps $1 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=1400 -ffourcc DIVX -vf scale=640:360 -o $2
```

usage:  ./compile_move.sh  30  myFile.mp4
editing the bitrate, codec, etc is straightforward.

Version 2:

```
cat ~/scripts/compile_pngs_to_flash_movie.sh 
#!/bin/bash
#
# usage:
#./compile_pngs_to_flash_movie.sh  my_funky_movie.flv

output_movie="$1"
mencoder mf://*.png -mf w=736:h=246:fps=20:type=png -of lavf -ffourcc FLV1 -ovc lavc -   lavcopts vcodec=flv -o "${output_movie}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best tool I have found that does this is [dvd-slideshow](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net).  It creates a dvd-compatible mpeg2 video from a bunch of images.  You can add music if you want also. Supports several effects like fadein/fadeout/crossfade/crop/kenburns.  I use it to make family memories type dvd's.

It runs on any *nux easily, though I've never installed it on windows, so if that's your target OS, I don't know what hurdles you might face with it.  It's a bash script.  On windows, at a minimum you'd want to start by installing [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Picasa 3 has a feature that does exactly this - basically, it saves the slideshow into a saved video file - works nicely.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com) or [Microsoft Photo Story](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11132).

[image]

Comment: idober provided a link to "These JPG files are usually from a web camera that has been set to take pictures every few seconds.". This is stopmotion.

Comment: Er... it was JPGVideo's software description AND it didn't work for idober is it? Dude, it wasn't me who downvoted you!

Comment: Besides, "stopmotion" in the real application of the word refers actually to "stop-motion animation", like Wallace and Gromit.

Comment: This's not revenge, i really believe the answer is not appropriate, sorry :) And yeah, u're right this's not an application name, but i saw it in Ubuntu packages recently :)

Comment: Don't be sorry, it's perfectly alright. Anyway chill, this is the Internets after all. ;)

Comment: -1 MS link leads into nowhereland